Maintainable! OpenVAS-Installation with eMail-Support in AWS
As the greenbone-community-edition docker-compose containers don't support eMail sending in OpenVAS, does someone have a maintainable! OpenVAS Installation running in AWS?
I had a manually compiled installation running, but updating this is a nightmare.
As i see it, there's only Kali Linux having OpenVAS in its repository.
I don't want to use a Marketplace AMI though, tried to vmimport a local Kali installation, but without success so far.
Running kali-rolling in docker is not good, since no systemd and OpenVAS consists of many systemd Services i don't want to manually override/change the startup script.
Ubuntu 24.04 has OpenVAS, but is missing the JS frontend package.
There's Arch linux with orphaned OpenVAS AUR packages...
Installing Kali repositories in a Debian system is also not a great idea, either.
AWS does not support nested Virtualization.
Running some random guys repositories also seems the be the wrong way..
Any ideas?
Anyone running OpenVAS in AWS?

Only as a comment to this:

As the greenbone-community-edition docker-compose containers don't support eMail sending in OpenVAS"

Noticed https://greenbone.github.io/docs/latest/22.4/container/workflows.html#setting-up-a-mail-transport-agent-inside-docker-container which could help?

Thanks. That's working. Albeit i have to apt install ca-certificates, otherwise i get TLS cert check errors (and i don't want to use the disable TLS check env var).
Gonna modify my docker-compose to automatically do this with the gvmd container and see where it goes.
